# Icon conditional formatting not working when formula present

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply icon conditional formatting in a cell.  The cell contains the following formula: `=VLOOKUP(D20,'owssvr(1)'!O:W,9,FALSE`

The formula results in a "2", "1", "0" or "-1" in the cell.
The icon conditional formatting is not working at all (no icon appears).

If I delete the formula and just type in any of those numbers directly, it works.
I have changed my cells to "number" and it still does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your VLOOKUP is probably returning a text value - you can't make that a number by changing formatting - try adding +0 to the end of the formula which will convert a text formatted number to a real number, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(D20,'owssvr(1)'!O:W,9,FALSE)+0`